# Javascript undefined function inside module

Tags: javascript

Given the following Javascript example:

```
var obj = function() {
    var _c = function() {
        console.log("c")
    }
    return {
        a: function() {
            b();
        },
        b: function() {
             console.log("b");
        },
        c: function() {
            _c();
        }
    }
}();
```

calling `obj.a()` gives an error that b is not defined. This error can be solved by changing `b()` to `this.b()`. Can anyone help explain why this is necessary while `c` can access `_c`?

Comment: Because `b` is a property, not a variable.

Comment: There is no `function b()`, there is just `{b : function() {}}` which is completely different, it's a property of an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_c` is a local variable that is in scope when `_c()` is executed. `b` is not; it is only found on the object itself, so it can be found by `this.b`.

This confusion is indicative of transplanting object-oriented concepts from other languages to JavaScript. There are no private and public members in JS, and you can't call methods on the same object by leaving the object prefix. There's just local variables (`v` when `var v` or `let v`), global variables (`v` when no `var v` or `let v`) and object properties (`obj.prop`). A method is object property that contains a function; no more, no less.

Comment: Good explanation. It's worth mentioning that a call to a bare `b()` would execute if there were a global function `b` (albeit not calling the function that OP would expect). Also, I think you meant that `_c` is _"a local variable that is in scope when `c()`_ [not _`_c()`_] _is defined"_ [not _executed_]; this is actually a closure, which would be another good JS concept for OP to understand..

Answer (score 0):

Need to use `this.b`  because you are returning an object and 'b' in this context is the property of that object. you need to explicitly stated that using `this`

While _c is a local function defined inside the closure, you can access access it directly in the return object and does not refer to the return object.

Answer (score -1):

You should not call b() directly.

```
var obj = function() {
  var _c = function() {
      console.log("c")
  }
  return {
      b: function() {
           console.log("b");
      },
      a: function() {
          this.b();
      },
      c: function() {
          _c();
      }
  }
}();
obj.a();
```

**Explanation added :** 
You are calling b() inside a function where b() is defined on the object. So to call the function b() inside any other function, you should **call b with reference to the object** like

```
this.b();
```

Comment: This does not answer the question "Can anyone help explain why this is necessary while c can access _c?"

Comment: @MobyDisk sorry my bad, forgot to add the explanation.